# storing user defined object in some where in android

Tags: android

HELLO FREINDS ,

I am developing one android application i want to store user defind objects for fututre so how i can achieve this can anyone help me because for this small thing i dont want to use database.

plz help me 
Thanks &Regards 
pawan pathak

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) or [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) (the latter works if you know in advance how many objects you will store, e.g. a configuration class).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the database, you can [Serialize](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) them to the SD Card or the app data location.

Answer (score 0):

You may serealize it and save as text file. Then when you need this object you have just to read file and deserealize it in you object. For primitive data types it's better to use Shared Preferences.